# Load time payment method One page checkout very long

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, magento

I'm using the magento onepagecheckout extension from IWD but the load time of the payment method when customers click on order is very long! What can i do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Magento One Page Checkout Extension](http://magento.ocodewire.com/extensions/one-page-checkout.html) for checkout process without facing any kind of difficulty, loading time and increase your website sales conversion exponentially.